# javascript using Aptana debugger can't set breakpoints using

Tags: javascript

Here is some info on what I have installed.

1. aptana studio 3.05 as a plugin for eclipse 3.7
2. firefox 8.0
3. firebug 1.9.05a

I am trying to set a breakpoint within the debugger on a field within a function. When I right-click on the shaded area to the left in the grey area there is no option to set a breakpoint.
I tried to set one on another field and there doesn't seem to be an option 
for any field or function.
One of the options that is is available when i right-click on the shaded 
area to the left is "add bookmark". 
Does anyone know what the problem might be?.

Answer (score 0):

Try to double click the blue-circle-position, which left to line-number.

Maybe you open the js file with wrong editor. In the left Project Navigator view, right click the js file, and chose Open with..., in the sub menu, click the right editor.

Comment: ijse, if you mean the blue-circle that collapses and uncollapses, i tried that and it only collapses and uncollapses but it does not

Comment: ijse, if you mean the circle that collapses or uncollapses when you double-click on it I did try that and it only collapses or uncollapses but does not show anything to set the breakpoints.

Comment: Maybe you open the js file with wrong editor. In the left Project Navigator view, right click the js file, and chose Open with..., in the sub menu, click the right editor.